# How to Load an array into OpenFlow

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

I'm trying to implement openFlow in my project but I cant seem to get the images to show up on my uiview.  What isnt clear to me is once I have the dictionary of image links, how do i tell AFOpenView that I want to use that dictionary object as my data source?

I've looked at the demo code and I see that when the flickr request finishes, he saves a copy of the dictionary results, counts them, and then tells OpenFlowView that there are x number of images, but what is never clear is how he tells OpenFlowView to use the dictionary with the results?

```
- (void)flickrAPIRequest:(OFFlickrAPIRequest *)inRequest didCompleteWithResponse:(NSDictionary *)inResponseDictionary
{
 // Hold onto the response dictionary.
 interestingPhotosDictionary = [inResponseDictionary retain];
 int numberOfImages = [[inResponseDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"photos.photo"] count];
 [(AFOpenFlowView *)self.view setNumberOfImages:numberOfImages];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here: http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2010/04/09/how-to-add-coverflow-effect-on-your-iphone-app-openflow/

This tutorial seems to suggest that you have to call the view's setImage method multiple times, once per image.

This tells me that the implementation is confusing and weird, but for this you have to blame the component's author.

Comment: Ugh yeah this seems to be the case...Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

The images are loaded on demand in the 'updateCoverImage:' method of AFOpenFlowView.m

'updateCoverImage:' calls 'openFlowView:requestImageForIndex:' in AFOpenFlowViewController.m, which uses interestingPhotosDictionary.

So, it is called on demand whenever an image needs to be loaded.  It wraps an operation queue so the images are loaded outside the main thread.

Comment: but the whole purpose of the question was how does it know to use InterestingPhotosDictionary as the source for the pictures?